# VBScript Download Multiple Images from the TARGET URL

Tags: image, vbscript, stream, xmlhttprequest

```
Dim xhr
Dim document
Dim stream 
set document = WScript.GetObject("TARGET URL")
While document.readyState <> "complete"
    WScript.Sleep 200
Wend
set xhr = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.3.0")
xhr.open "GET", document.getElementsByTagName("img")(0).src, False xhr.send
set stream = CreateObject("Adodb.Stream")
with stream
    .type = 1
    .Open
    .Write xhr.responsebody
    .SaveToFile "C:\Users\bebebe\Desktop\a.jpg", 2
end with 
set stream = nothing
set xhr = nothing
stream.Close
```

Above is my code and I am trying to download multiple images from "TARGET URL".

The best solution I am currently looking for is to download the multiple images through VBS but VBA is also possible option.

From the above VBScript, I am not sure how to put a loop around with Stream to download multiple images from the designated URL..

Comment: This is a repeat of your [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51381719/). Please don't post the same question multiple times. You have to give people time to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know how to write a loop (you are using one already).  Simply replace `getElementsByTagName("img")(0)` with `getElementsByTagName("img")(index)`, where `index` is a variable that the loop increments. `getElementsByTagName("img")` returns a collection that you can query for its `count` to know how many times to loop.

```
Dim document
Dim xhr
Dim images
Dim index
Dim stream 
set document = WScript.GetObject("TARGET URL")
While document.readyState <> "complete"
  WScript.Sleep 200
Wend
set xhr = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.3.0")
set images = document.getElementsByTagName("img")
For index = 0 To images.count-1
  xhr.open "GET", images(index).src, False
  xhr.send
  set stream = CreateObject("Adodb.Stream")
  with stream
    .type = 1
    .Open
    .Write xhr.responsebody
    .SaveToFile "C:\Users\bebebe\Desktop\" + CStr(index) + ".jpg", 2
  end with 
  stream.Close
  set stream = nothing
Next
set images = nothing
set xhr = nothing
set document = nothing
```

Or, you can enumerate the collection using a `for each` loop:

```
Dim document
Dim xhr
Dim images
Dim image
Dim index
Dim stream 
set document = WScript.GetObject("TARGET URL")
While document.readyState <> "complete"
  WScript.Sleep 200
Wend
set xhr = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.3.0")
set images = document.getElementsByTagName("img")
set index = 0
For each image in images
  xhr.open "GET", image.src, False
  xhr.send
  set stream = CreateObject("Adodb.Stream")
  with stream
    .type = 1
    .Open
    .Write xhr.responsebody
    .SaveToFile "C:\Users\bebebe\Desktop\" + CStr(index) + ".jpg", 2
  end with 
  stream.Close
  set stream = nothing
  index = index + 1 
Next
set images = nothing
set xhr = nothing
set document = nothing
```